# Markovchains number of passages in a set

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chain

$\eta_A$ is the number of passages of a markovchain $(X_n)$ on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ in a set $A$ and $P_x(\eta_A = \infty)$ is the probability of visiting $A$ infinite often. $\mathbb{E}_x[\eta_A]$ ist the average number of passages in $A$.

Show that if $P_x(\eta_A \ = \infty) \neq 0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}_x[\eta_A] = \infty$

proof :
From 
$ 0 \neq P_x(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} I_A(X_n) = \infty)$ it follows

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \underbrace{P_x(X_n \in A)}_{infintely \ often \ > 0} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}K^n(x,A) = \mathbb{E}_x[\eta_A] = \infty$

But on the other hand it does not hold that $P_x(\eta_A \ = \infty) = 0$ imply $\mathbb{E}_x[\eta_A] < \infty$ ? why ?

i am not sooo sure about this, what do you think ?